# How to find a solution of the Schrödinger equation that scatters to a given function.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the nonlinear Schrödinger equation
$$
 \left\{\begin{array}{l}
  i u_t + \Delta u = |u|^p u, \quad p > 0 \\
  u(0, x) = u_0(x) \in L^2
 \end{array}\right.
 $$
Given the initial data and the solution, I understand how to formally find scattering. Suppose $u$ is a forward solution to the initial data $u_0$, then it has the form:
$$
 u(t) = e^{i t \Delta} u_0 - i \int_0^t e^{i(t-s) \Delta}|u|^p u(s) \, ds
 $$
We have:
$$
 e^{-i t \Delta} u(t) = u_0 - i \int_0^t e^{-i s \Delta}|u|^p u(s) \, ds
 $$
Therefore, formally:
$$
 u_{+} = u_0 - i \int_0^{\infty} e^{-i s \Delta}|u|^p u(s) \, ds
 $$
which is the scattering.

My question is, given an $L^2$ function $\varphi(x)$, how can we find a solution $u$ that scatters to $e^{it \Delta}\varphi$? This means:
$$
 \left\|u(t,x) - e^{i t \Delta} \varphi\right\|_2 \rightarrow 0, \quad \text{as } t \rightarrow \infty
 $$